# Can I use Akka scheduler to schedule multiple things from a single actor context?

Tags: scala, akka, scheduler

I am trying to schedule two events using the Akka scheduler. One of them using the `context.system.scheduler.schedule(0 milliseconds, 100 milliseconds, receiver: ActorRef, message: Any)` and another using `scheduleOnce(1 seconds, receiver: ActorRef, message: Any)`.

Both messages are passed to different receivers (the former to a persistence actor and the latter to client actor via self). I see that the scheduleOnce is never being executed. If I comment out the code for `schedule` I can see `scheduleOnce` being executed fine. Is there something in the scheduler which prevents multiple schedules from a single actor? I tried to cancel the cancellable from the former scheduler before performing the action when the message is received in the self from the second scheduler but that didn't help. I am at a loss here. Any thoughts/suggestions on what could be going wrong?

Comment: No, there's not a real reason why they should influence each other. It could be an instance of thread starvation where enough tasks are blocking to wait for a result so that the whole thread pool is exhausted. See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.11/general/actor-systems.html#Blocking_Needs_Careful_Management. Try `jstack <pid>` to see what the threads in the pool are doing.

Comment: Can you share some more code.  That will help with diagnosing the issue.